# Database schema advice for a user-inter-messaging feature on a PHP-driven website

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema, database-performance

I have a user driven website. I want to add a messaging feature. My concerns revolve around my database's manageability and performance.

I'm thinking about organizing it like this: I have my users table and all my users have unique id's
Any user-initiated conversation between two users would have a record in 'conversations' and all messages in that conversation would use foreign keys that reference that conversation_id.

Can anyone think of any reasons not to go with this approach? I'm wondering how well it will perform long-term, provided I use indexes and limit my queries to ~20 results for each page.

```
+--------+
| users  |
+--------+
|users_id|
|        |
+--------+

+-------------+
|conversations|
+-------------+
|id           |
|user_id1     |
|user_id2     |
+-------------+

+----------------------+
|conversations_messages|
+----------------------+
|id                    |
|conversations_id      | 
|message_body (varchar)|
|message_time (unix timestamp
+----------------------+
```

Edit:
I've realized I have no way to track who's the sender/receiver. My first instinct is to simply add a 'sender' column to conversations_messages

Comment: I have concerns about the 'user_id1' / 'user_id2' columns. If you ever want more than two people in the conversation, you'd have to change it, and to find all conversations a single user is in, you'll have to do check both columns.

Comment: @Doug Kress, that's an interesting point. Do you have any proposed alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541302/thread-messaging-system-database-schema-design/6542556#6542556).  I address a similar design problem there.  It includes handling of who has seen which messages and who is the sender of each message.

Comment: Thanks @Joel Brown, that was a very well thought out response it certainly helped me!