# Sqlalchemy thread messaging system

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask, relationship

I'm newbie to sqlalchemy. Now developing site with Flask. I want to orginize message system with threads. Something like facebook dialogs. I have following models and this code works:

```
message_read_state_relations = db.Table('message_message_read_state_relations',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('auth_users.id')),
        db.Column('message_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('messages.id')),
)

class User(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'auth_users'

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        email = db.Column(db.String(100))
        password = db.Column(db.String(100))

        messages = db.relationship('Message', backref=db.backref('user'), lazy='dynamic')

        threads = association_proxy('user_thread_relations', 'thread')


class Message(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'messages'

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        text = db.Column(db.Text, default='')

        thread_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('threads.id'))
        user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('auth_users.id'))

        user_read_states = db.relationship('User', secondary=message_read_state_relations,
                backref=db.backref('message_read_states'), lazy='joined')


class Thread(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'threads'

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        subject = db.Column(db.String(255))

        messages = db.relationship('Message', backref=db.backref('thread'), lazy='dynamic')
        users = association_proxy('user_thread_relations', 'user')


class UserThreadRelation(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'user_thread_relations'

        user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('auth_users.id'), primary_key=True)
        thread_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('threads.id'), primary_key=True)

        is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

        user = db.relationship(User, backref=db.backref('user_thread_relations'))
        thread = db.relationship(Thread, backref=db.backref('user_thread_relations'))
```

But I can't understand some things. For example, how can I get all unread messages count for user? Or unread messages count for user in some thread?

`Message` has relation to `User` via `message_read_state_relations`. How can I get all messages that belongs to all threads that belongs to user without `message_read_state_relations` to this user?

Or, maybe, I'm doing all wrong way? Is design is wrong? I created it on the basis of this question [thread messaging system database schema design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541302/thread-messaging-system-database-schema-design)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it's the best possible design, seems to be reasonable. Regarding the queries you asked about, they can be constructed using joins and subqueries, you may want to read about them in SQLAlchemy docs. I'd also recommend to get familiar with pure SQL approach on queries like that, since SA tries to follow SQL pretty closely, and understanding SQL helps to write SA queries immensely. Here's an example of one query (get all unread messages count for user):

```
# First count all the messages.
# On a big set of data this may be very slow operation.
total_msgs = db.session.query(db.func.count(Message.id).label('cnt')).subquery()
# Then count messages read by the user.
read_msgs = db.session.query(db.func.count(Message.id).label('cnt')).\
    join(User.message_read_states).filter(User.id == 1).subquery()
# Subtract read messages count from total count.
unread_count = db.session.query(total_msgs.c.cnt - read_msgs.c.cnt).scalar()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not it =)

Here you get all unread messages that _User#1 created_. And I need to get all unread messages that belongs to all threads that belongs to User#1

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to develop a threaded message system with Flask and sqlalchemy. Searching I found your question and a github repository for django (link below). I reckon the model can be quite useful. If you're still interested (after 6 years), drop me a line.

https://github.com/philippWassibauer/django-threaded-messages/blob/master/threaded_messages/models.py