# StoredProcedure which return some records and Insert for each of them a row in a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm using this [Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541302/thread-messaging-system-database-schema-design/6542556#6542556) to do a message system in a asp.net MVC 4 Application with SQLServer 2012 Database.

[image: Schema]

Now i have 2 problem. When i select all messages from a thread conversation i should insert a record in the table MessageReadyState.

This is my StoredProcedure to get Message By ThreadId

```
  SELECT TOP(@NumberMessage)
  Message.MessageId
, Message.CreateDate
, Message.Body,Person.Name , Person.Surname,Utente.ID,MessageThread.MessageThreadId as MessageThreadID
, [User].Username,User.[Path] , Person.Image
, (SELECT MessageReadState.ReadDate 
   FROM MessageReadState 
   WHERE MessageReadState.MessageId = Message.MessageId 
     and MessageReadState.UserId = @UserId) as ReadState
FROM (Message INNER JOIN [Utente] ON Message.SenderUserId = [Utente].ID 
       INNER JOIN MessageThread ON MessageThread.MessageThreadId = Message.MessageThreadId
              INNER JOIN Person ON Person .ID = User.Id_person) 
WHERE ([Message].MessageThreadId=@ThreadId)
ORDER BY Message.CreateDate DESC;
END
```

Now the Stored Procedure should return the select but also for each row it should insert a row in MessageReadState, how i could do that?

Edit: Of course , this should be done only the first time that i read the message. I wondering if there is a better solution , in term of a database schema.
Another question..

How could i know if the user has news messages?
I mean i should check the messages in a Thread which havent a row in MessageReadState?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is put the results of your query in a temp table, then insert the UserId & MessageId into the MessageReadState, checking if the combo MessageId/UserId does not exist already by checking if they are NULL.

```
SELECT TOP(@NumberMessage)
      Message.MessageId
    , Message.CreateDate
    , Message.Body,Person.Name , Person.Surname,Utente.ID,MessageThread.MessageThreadId as MessageThreadID
    , [User].Username,User.[Path] , Person.Image
    , (SELECT MessageReadState.ReadDate 
       FROM MessageReadState 
       WHERE MessageReadState.MessageId = Message.MessageId 
         and MessageReadState.UserId = @UserId) as ReadState
    INTO #messages
    FROM (Message INNER JOIN [Utente] ON Message.SenderUserId = [Utente].ID 
           INNER JOIN MessageThread ON MessageThread.MessageThreadId = Message.MessageThreadId
                  INNER JOIN Person ON Person .ID = User.Id_person) 
    WHERE ([Message].MessageThreadId=@ThreadId)
    ORDER BY Message.CreateDate DESC;

    INSERT INTO MessageReadState
    (
      MessageId,
      UserId,
      MessageReadData
    )
    SELECT MessageId,
           UserId,
           'read data'
    FROM #messages m
    LEFT JOIN MessageReadState mrd
      on m.MessageId = mrd.MessageId
      and m.UserId = mrd.UserId
    WHERE mrd.MessageId IS NULL AND mrd.UserId IS NULL;

    DROP TABLE #Messages;
```